# Weeding duplicates from a list of functions

Tags: function, haskell, duplicates

Is it possible to remove the duplicates (as in nub) from a list of functions in Haskell?
Basically, is it possible to add an instance for (Eq (Integer -> Integer))

In ghci:

```
let fs = [(+2), (*2), (^2)]
let cs = concat $ map subsequences $ permutations fs
nub cs

<interactive>:31:1:
No instance for (Eq (Integer -> Integer))
  arising from a use of `nub'
Possible fix:
  add an instance declaration for (Eq (Integer -> Integer))
In the expression: nub cs
In an equation for `it': it = nub cs
```

Thanks in advance.

...

Further, based on larsmans' answer, I am now able to do this

```
> let fs = [AddTwo, Double, Square]
> let css = nub $ concat $ map subsequences $ permutations fs
```

in order to get this

```
> css

[[],[AddTwo],[Double],[AddTwo,Double],[Square],[AddTwo,Square],[Double,Square],[AddTwo,Double,Square],[Double,AddTwo],[Double,AddTwo,Square],[Square,Double],[Square,AddTwo],[Square,Double,AddTwo],[Double,Square,AddTwo],[Square,AddTwo,Double],[AddTwo,Square,Double]]
```

and then this

```
> map (\cs-> call <$> cs <*> [3,4]) css

[[],[5,6],[6,8],[5,6,6,8],[9,16],[5,6,9,16],[6,8,9,16],[5,6,6,8,9,16],[6,8,5,6],[6,8,5,6,9,16],[9,16,6,8],[9,16,5,6],[9,16,6,8,5,6],[6,8,9,16,5,6],[9,16,5,6,6,8],[5,6,9,16,6,8]]
```

, which was my original intent.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, this is not possible. Functions cannot be compared for equality.

The reason for this is:

1. Pointer comparison makes very little sense for Haskell functions, since then the equality of `id` and `\x -> id x` would change based on whether the latter form is optimized into `id`.
2. Extensional comparison of functions is impossible, since it would require a positive solution to the halting problem (both functions having the same halting behavior is a necessary requirement for equality).

The workaround is to represent functions as data:

```
data Function = AddTwo | Double | Square deriving Eq

call AddTwo  =  (+2)
call Double  =  (*2)
call Square  =  (^2)
```

Answer (score 3):

No, it's not possible to do this for `Integer -> Integer` functions.

***However***, it *is* possible if you're also ok with a more general type signature `Num a => a -> a`, as your example indicates! One naïve way (not safe), would go like

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances           #-}
{-# LANGUAGE NoMonomorphismRestriction   #-}

data NumResLog a = NRL { runNumRes :: a, runNumResLog :: String }
             deriving (Eq, Show)

instance (Num a) => Num (NumResLog a) where
  fromInteger n = NRL (fromInteger n) (show n)
  NRL a alog + NRL b blog
            = NRL (a+b) ( "("++alog++ ")+(" ++blog++")" )
  NRL a alog * NRL b blog
            = NRL (a*b) ( "("++alog++ ")*(" ++blog++")" )
  ...


instance (Num a) => Eq (NumResLog a -> NumResLog a) where
  f == g  = runNumResLog (f arg) == runNumResLog (g arg)
     where arg = NRL 0 "THE ARGUMENT"

unlogNumFn :: (NumResLog a -> NumResLog c) -> (a->c)
unlogNumFn f = runNumRes . f . (`NRL`"")
```

which works basically by comparing a "normalised" version of the functions' source code. Of course this fails when you compare e.g. `(+1) == (1+)`, which are equivalent numerically but yield `"(THE ARGUMENT)+(1)"` vs. `"(1)+(THE ARGUMENT)"` and thus are indicated as non-equal. However, since functions `Num a => a->a` are essentially constricted to be polynomials (yeah, `abs` and `signum` make it a bit more difficult, but it's still doable), you can find a data type that properly handles those equivalencies.

The stuff can be used like this:

```
> let fs = [(+2), (*2), (^2)]
> let cs = concat $ map subsequences $ permutations fs
> let ncs = map (map unlogNumFn) $ nub cs
> map (map ($ 1)) ncs
[[],[3],[2],[3,2],[1],[3,1],[2,1],[3,2,1],[2,3],[2,3,1],[1,2],[1,3],[1,2,3],[2,1,3],[1,3,2],[3,1,2]]
```